# Erro no projeto: JSF não responde e nem mostra Message

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, spring-security

Estou em um projeto de estudo de JSF do livro Java Para Web. Estava indo bem, porém coloquei o seguinte código no JSF que, segundo atualizações, não deveria funcionar pois a biblioteca **facelets-taglib-jsf20-spring-3** foi removida, segundo o livro. Código abaixo:

```html
  <sec:ifAnyGranted roles="ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR">
 <h:commandLink action="/admin/principal" title="Administrativo">
  <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="administrativo16.png" />
 </h:commandLink>
</sec:ifAnyGranted>
```

Só que o código acima mostrou o .png administrativo e tals, chegou até a funcionar. O que não funcionou foi o sugerido por eles para que eu usasse, que é esse do código abaixo:

```html
  <h:panelGroup rendered="#{request.isUserInRole('ROLE_ADMINISTRADOR')}">
 <h:commandLink action="/admin/principal" title="Administrativo">
  <h:graphicImage library="imagens" name="administrativo16.png" />
 </h:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Agora, por que não funcionou? Não sei, no momento, nenhum dos dois está funcionando. A página não sai do lugar. Dá o erro abaixo, sendo que verifiquei os dados que estão indo no objeto e estão tudo ok

```html
INFORMAÇÕES: AVISO: FacesMessage(s) foram enfileirados, mas podem não ter sido exibidos.
sourceId=j_idt6:j_idt8[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt6:j_idt8: 'br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.conta.Conta@82f67b77' deve ser um número formado por um ou mais dígitos.), detail=(j_idt6:j_idt8: 'br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.conta.Conta@82f67b77' deve ser um número entre -2147483648 e 2147483647 Exemplo: 9346)]
```

Log do erro completo:

```html
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
ADVERTÊNCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:financeiro' did not find a matching property.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server built:          Nov 27 2017 13:05:30 UTC
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Server number:         8.5.24.0
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Name:               Windows 10
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: OS Version:            10.0
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Architecture:          amd64
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Version:           1.8.0_151-b12
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Desenvolvimento\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Desenvolvimento\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.24
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:51956
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Desenvolvimento\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Desenvolvimento\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.24
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Desenvolvimento\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Desenvolvimento\Server\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\endorsed
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFORMAÇÕES: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFORMAÇÕES: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\jre\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_161/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\php-7.1;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Filipe Lobato\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Desenvolvimento\IDE\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
abr 16, 2018 9:52:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:40 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFORMAÇÕES: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
abr 16, 2018 9:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFORMAÇÕES: Initialization processed in 2396 ms
abr 16, 2018 9:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting service [Catalina]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.24
abr 16, 2018 9:52:46 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
ADVERTÊNCIA: Name = FinanceiroDB Property maxActive is not used in DBCP2, use maxTotal instead. maxTotal default value is 8. You have set value of "100" for "maxActive" property, which is being ignored.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory getObjectInstance
ADVERTÊNCIA: Name = FinanceiroDB Property maxWait is not used in DBCP2 , use maxWaitMillis instead. maxWaitMillis default value is -1. You have set value of "10000" for "maxWait" property, which is being ignored.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFORMAÇÕES: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFORMAÇÕES: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMAÇÕES: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
abr 16, 2018 9:52:52 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFORMAÇÕES: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 16 21:52:52 GFT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
abr 16, 2018 9:52:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFORMAÇÕES: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:53 PM org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion performVersionChecks
INFORMAÇÕES: You are running with Spring Security Core 3.2.6.RELEASE
abr 16, 2018 9:52:53 PM org.springframework.security.config.SecurityNamespaceHandler <init>
INFORMAÇÕES: Spring Security 'config' module version is 3.2.6.RELEASE
abr 16, 2018 9:52:53 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser checkFilterChainOrder
INFORMAÇÕES: Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 400, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1900, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:53 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFORMAÇÕES: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@50dccf13: defining beans [financeiroDataSource,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.RememberMeAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]; root of factory hierarchy
abr 16, 2018 9:52:54 PM org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao
INFORMAÇÕES: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:54 PM org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager initDao
INFORMAÇÕES: No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:54 PM org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain <init>
INFORMAÇÕES: Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4251a86c, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@6f2b8423, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@400ebaf6, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@1f5530ea, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5008e9a4, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@63b1751a, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@56ddba90, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter@60b902c1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@77eb92bb, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@1f9a30f9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@242810a0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@cafb1ee]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:54 PM org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator checkLoginPageIsntProtected
INFORMAÇÕES: Checking whether login URL '/publico/login.jsf' is accessible with your configuration
abr 16, 2018 9:52:54 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFORMAÇÕES: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1973 ms
abr 16, 2018 9:52:54 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFORMAÇÕES: Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) para o contexto '/financeiro'
abr 16, 2018 9:52:55 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFORMAÇÕES: JSF1048: Anotações PostConstruct/PreDestroy presentes.  Os métodos ManagedBeans marcados com essas anotações informarão as anotações processadas.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:55 PM com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl getProjectStage
INFORMAÇÕES: Unable to discern ProjectStage for value Development>.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:56 PM com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor getProjectStage
INFORMAÇÕES: Unable to discern ProjectStage for value Development>.
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.4.Final}
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.4.Final}
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: hibernate.cfg.xml
abr 16, 2018 9:52:57 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
abr 16, 2018 9:52:58 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
abr 16, 2018 9:52:58 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
abr 16, 2018 9:52:58 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: financeiro.Conta
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [saldoinicial, datacadastro, conta, favorita, usuario_codigo, descricao]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_b0vqbmuwlxgrx3y022unu4lg8]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [fk_b0vqbmuwlxgrx3y022unu4lg8, primary]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: financeiro.Usuario
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [senha, codigo, ativo, nascimento, celular, idioma, nome, login, email]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [primary, uk_fl3uvb053wjkjly059t4j7xjp]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000261: Table found: financeiro.usuario_permissao
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000037: Columns: [usuario, permissao]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000108: Foreign keys: [fk_7r68xb5pbmiv8t38y92ak3dx2]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata <init>
INFO: HHH000126: Indexes: [uk_sent4jkw3tncsd39oduptyq3j]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000232: Schema update complete
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMAÇÕES: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
abr 16, 2018 9:52:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFORMAÇÕES: Server startup in 19272 ms
abr 16, 2018 9:54:20 PM com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitUtils renderUnhandledMessages
INFORMAÇÕES: AVISO: FacesMessage(s) foram enfileirados, mas podem não ter sido exibidos.
sourceId=j_idt6:j_idt8[severity=(ERROR 2), summary=(j_idt6:j_idt8: 'br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.conta.Conta@82f67b77' deve ser um número formado por um ou mais dígitos.), detail=(j_idt6:j_idt8: 'br.com.javaparaweb.financeiro.conta.Conta@82f67b77' deve ser um número entre -2147483648 e 2147483647 Exemplo: 9346)]
```

Para quem quiser ver o código do projeto completo segue o link abaixo:
[Projeto de Estudo - Financeiro - Java para Web](https://gitlab.com/filipelobato/financeiro)

O erro fica aqui, quando clico no *Boneco* ou na *Conta* [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade o erro não tem a ver com o trecho que você está em dúvida. Na mensagem de erro consta o seguinte:

```
sourceId=j_idt6:j_idt8
```

Quando criamos uma página JSF cada componente pode (deve) ter um id, porque quando dá um erro fica mais fácil de saber onde ele aconteceu, o que está acontecendo é que o campo de id j_idt6:j_idt8 (sim, nada útil de acompanhar, porque foi gerado automaticamente por não ter sido informado) precisa de um valor numérico válido. Suspeito que você esteja tentando atribuir o banco para a Conta (ou alguma coisa similar).

Aquele combobox que aparece provavelmente vem de um SelectOneMenu, experimente colocar a tag id (aproximadamente) assim:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="conta" ... > 
...
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Isso deve ajudar a encontrar o problema da página para só depois você continuar o estudo relacionado ao problema de segurança.